# What vendors offer mobile geolocation targeting and analytics SDKs?

Tags: mobile, geolocation, analytics, targeting

I'm conducting a vendor analysis for an enterprise level organization. I'm looking for a SDK I can integrate with an iOS/Android application that does the following well:

1. Location Analytics
2. Geo-fencing around locations specified by the organization
3. Push Notifications (specific to geo-fences, time zones, and customer segmentation)
4. Easy to use console
5. Doesn't noticeably drain the battery
6. They also need to be advanced in their field--ideally they'd have some sort of beaconing
   capability in their product or planned down the line to support indoor location awareness

Some examples I'm looking at are Geoloqi, Xtify and Urban Airship. Do you have any experiences with those or similar vendors?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the [proxim.io](http://proxim.io/) API is exactly what you are looking for. Here is a quote from the API documentation page:

> Proxim.io is a platform for delivering relevant messages to your
>   application users. Messages that are delivered based on real-time
>   location, topics of interest, and geo-triggers. Messages can be
>   delivered to a device via Push, or can be routed to a software system
>   through an API (Web Events).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen Xtify do most of these. With Push Notification it has support for tags which can help in sending message to subset of users. It has a location API. The console can use used to upload basic credentials, test sending messages and some basic analytic view.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Leantegra has all you need: there is back end solution; appropriate hardware and mobile SDKs for Android and iOS.